# How to get within R squared from plm FE regression?

Tags: r, plm

I regress monthly stocks returns on a set of firm characteristics using the `plm` package.

```
library(plm)
set.seed(1)
id=rep(1:10,each=10); t=rep(1:10,10); industry=rep(1:2,each=50); return=rnorm(100); x=rnorm(100)
data=data.frame(id,t,industry,return,x)
```

In a first step, I want to include time fixed effects. The following two formulas give the same coefficients for `x` but different R-squares. The first model estimates the overall R-squared, while the second model gives the within R-squared.

```
reg1=plm(return~x+factor(t),model="pooling",index=c("id","t"),data=data)
summary(reg1)$r.squared

reg2=plm(return~x,model="within",index=c("id","t"),data=data,effect="time")
summary(reg2)$r.squared
```

In a second step, I now want to include both time and industry fixed effects. I obtain coefficients by this formula:

```
reg3=plm(return~x+factor(t)+factor(industry),model="pooling",index=c("id","t"), data=data)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use the `"within"` model as in `reg2` because `industry` is not one of my index variables. Is there another way to calculate the within R-squared for `reg3`?

Comment: To include time and industry effects (next to individual effects), just use `plm(return~x + factor(industry), model="within", effect = "twoways", index=c("id","t"), data=data)`, i.e., make use of the two-way model and include any further fixed effects by `+factor(eff)` in the formula.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, because I am not sure
`plm` can do this. (It might, but I can’t figure it out.)

However, if you are mainly estimating fixed effects models, then I can
warmly recommend [the `fixest`
package,](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/) which is super fast and
offers a convenient formula syntax to specify fixed effects and
interactions. Here’s a simple example:

```r
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)

dat = read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/plm/EmplUK.csv")

models = list(
    feols(wage ~ emp | year, data = dat),
    feols(wage ~ emp | firm, data = dat),
    feols(wage ~ emp | firm + year, data = dat)
)

modelsummary(models)
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 | Model 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| emp | -0.039 | -0.120 | -0.047 |
|  | (0.003) | (0.064) | (0.042) |
| Num.Obs. | 1031 | 1031 | 1031 |
| R2 | 0.039 | 0.868 | 0.896 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.030 | 0.847 | 0.879 |
| R2 Within | 0.012 | 0.016 | 0.003 |
| R2 Pseudo |  |  |  |
| AIC | 6474.0 | 4687.7 | 4455.6 |
| BIC | 6523.4 | 5384.0 | 5191.4 |
| Log.Lik. | -3226.988 | -2202.833 | -2078.818 |
| Std.Errors | by: year | by: firm | by: firm |
| FE: year | X |  | X |
| FE: firm |  | X | X |

Comment: that is a great suggestion +1!

Answer (score 0):

To include time and industry effects (next to individual effects), just use a two-ways within model and include any further fixed effects by `+ factor(eff)` in the formula.

For your example, this would be:

```
reg3 <- plm(return ~ x + factor(industry), model="within", effect = "twoways", index=c("id","t"), data = data)
summary(reg3)
# Twoways effects Within Model
# 
# Call:
# plm(formula = return ~ x + factor(industry), data = data, effect = "twoways", 
#     model = "within", index = c("id", "t"))
# 
# Balanced Panel: n = 10, T = 10, N = 100
# 
# Residuals:
#     Min.  1st Qu.   Median  3rd Qu.     Max. 
# -1.84660 -0.61135  0.06318  0.57474  2.06264 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)
# x 0.050906   0.112408  0.4529   0.6519
# 
# Total Sum of Squares:    68.526
# Residual Sum of Squares: 68.35
# R-Squared:      0.0025571
# Adj. R-Squared: -0.23434
# F-statistic: 0.20509 on 1 and 80 DF, p-value: 0.65187

summary(reg3)$r.squared
#         rsq       adjrsq 
# 0.002557064 -0.234335633
```

However, note that for your toy example data, the variable `industry` is collinear after the fixed effects transformation and, thus, drops out of the estimation (see `?detect.lindep` for an explanation and another example). Check via, e.g.:

```
detect.lindep(reg3)
# [1] "Suspicious column number(s): 2"
# [1] "Suspicious column name(s):   factor(industry)2"
```

Or via:

```
alias(reg3)
# Model :
# [1] "return ~ x + factor(industry)"
# 
# Complete :
#                   [,1]
# factor(industry)2 0
```